# What happens if a JS function name has the same name as the argument of the outer function?

Tags: javascript, scope

Why does the JS code below work when the function within var a is the same name as the argument, i.e. option?

```js
var fn = function(option) {
  var a = {
    option: function() {
      return option
    }
  }
  return {
    invoke: a.option
  }
}

console.log(fn("B").invoke()); //"B"
```

Comment: There's no conflict here, the second `option` is a property in an object, and is in fact `a.option` which is not the same as `option`

Comment: Your title and question ask very different things. :-)

Comment: I think I understand now. Within the a.option function, what 'a.option' stands for is not available unless the 'this' object is referred, such as in the code below: 
    -------var a = {
        option: function() {
          console.log("test");
          return this.option();
        }
    };
    
     a.option(); //test, test, test... (ad infinum)-----
So within a.option, 'option' can only refer to the argument 'option' of the outer function, thus there is no conflict between the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the code in your question: [As adeneo said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884041/what-happens-if-a-js-function-name-has-the-same-name-as-the-argument-of-the-oute/45884166#comment78726834_45884041), there's no conflict at all. The `option` parameter and the `option` property live in two completely different namespaces, as it were. The parameter is part of the context of the call to the function*, whereas the property is a property on the object. Within your outer function, `option` refers to the parameter, and `a.option` (after the assignment) would refer to the inner function.

---

But to your title:

> What happens if a JS function name has the same name as the argument of the outer function?

That's a very different thing. It would look like this:

```js
var fn = function(option) {
    console.log(typeof option); // "function"
    function option() {
      // ...
    }
};
fn("B");
```

In this situation, there is a conflict, and the function declaration within the function wins, overriding the parameter.

---

* Specifically, the [Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-environment-records) for the Execution Context created by calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

One of the option declaration is an agreement passed to the function and the other is an object key.

```
fn("B") // sends B to the option method. 

fn("B").invoke() // sends B to the option method and the invokes the value to be called.
```

The option method stores the argument as a private variable. Invoke makes use of that private variable.

Comment: *"sends B to the option method and the invokes the value to be called"* No, that's incorrect. It sends `"B"` to the `fn` function as an argument; the function receives it as the `option` parameter, and uses it via the closure `a.option`. Nothing ever passes `"B"` to the "option method."